# Alinear ul ajustando alto

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una tienda para un clinete y estoy tratando de alinear el listado que hice de la siguiente como la imagen, pero no puedo hacer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejo el codigo

```css
ul.products-wrp {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 780px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;  
 color: #777;  
 text-align: center;
}
ul.products-wrp li{
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ECECEC;
 margin: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
ul.products-wrp li h4{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px 5px 5px 5px;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
}
ul.products-wrp li .item-box{
 border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
 background: #F9F9F9;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
}
ul.products-wrp li .item-box div{
 margin-bottom:5px;
}
ul.products-wrp li .item-box button{
 margin-left: 5px;
 background: #FA1C5F;
 border: none;
 padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
 color: #fff;
}
ul.products-wrp li .item-box button[disabled=disabled]{
 background: #FC84A8;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products-wrp">
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>Campera</h4>
<div><img src="https://dafitistaticar-a.akamaihd.net/p/chelsea-market-6460-388122-1-product.jpg" width="200"></div>
<div>$300<div>
<div class="item-box">
 <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
 </div>
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>Zapato</h4>
<div><img src="https://bizarro.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/428124-720-720/ZAPATOS-MUJER-675-SINTETICO-FLOTER-KS_8328.jpg?v=636608529809230000" width="200"></div>
<div>$300<div>
<div class="item-box">
 <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
 </div>
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>Vestido</h4>
<div><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="200"></div>
<div>$300<div>
<div class="item-box">
 <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
 </div>
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>Remera</h4>
<div><img src="http://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/stores/782/214/products/blanco1-5640aa98e12c874f3415262392585105-640-0.jpg" width="200"></div>
<div>$300<div>
<div class="item-box">
 <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
 </div>
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con `inline-flex` asi:

```css
ul.products-wrp {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 780px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;  
 color: #777;  
 text-align: center;
}
ul.products-wrp li{
 display: inline-flex;
 border: 1px solid #ECECEC;
 margin: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
ul.products-wrp li h4{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px 5px 5px 5px;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
}
ul.products-wrp li .item-box{
 border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
 background: #F9F9F9;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;
}
ul.products-wrp li .item-box div{
 margin-bottom:5px;
}
ul.products-wrp li .item-box button{
 margin-left: 5px;
 background: #FA1C5F;
 border: none;
 padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
 color: #fff;
}
ul.products-wrp li .item-box button[disabled=disabled]{
 background: #FC84A8;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products-wrp">
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>Campera</h4>
<div><img src="https://dafitistaticar-a.akamaihd.net/p/chelsea-market-6460-388122-1-product.jpg" width="200"></div>
<div>$300<div>
<div class="item-box">
 <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
 </div>
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>Zapato</h4>
<div><img src="https://bizarro.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/428124-720-720/ZAPATOS-MUJER-675-SINTETICO-FLOTER-KS_8328.jpg?v=636608529809230000" width="200"></div>
<div>$300<div>
<div class="item-box">
 <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
 </div>
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>Vestido</h4>
<div><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="200"></div>
<div>$300<div>
<div class="item-box">
 <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
 </div>
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>Remera</h4>
<div><img src="http://d26lpennugtm8s.cloudfront.net/stores/782/214/products/blanco1-5640aa98e12c874f3415262392585105-640-0.jpg" width="200"></div>
<div>$300<div>
<div class="item-box">
 <div>
    Qty :
    <select name="product_qty">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
 </div>
    <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="{$row["product_code"]}">
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</div>
</form>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: gracias, pero queda un espacio entre la imagen de arriba y la de abajo, me refiero al la del zapato